# N-Body problen: Efficient parallelization of the double for loop

Tags: math, optimization, parallel-processing

A very common problem on a N-body problem is the use of a double cycle to calculate the interactions between the particles. Considering a N body problem with n particles, the cycle can be written has

```
for (i = 0, i < n; i++)
    for (j = i+1, j < n; j++)
        // calculate interaction
```

My question is about how can this cycle be parallelized using different threads. The objective is that each thread would "ideally" have to calculate the same number of interactions.

My idea was to separate the outer cycle, the i-cycle, on different intervals, say a_k=a(k), where k = 1,2,...,p where p is the number of threads we want to divide the problem into.

So, the cycle could be written as

```
for (k = 1, k < p; k++)
    for (i = a(k), i < a(k+1); i++)
        for (j = i+1, j < n; j++)
            // calculate interaction
```

Where the most outer cycle, the k-cycle, is the one to be parallelized.

Because the number of interactions of the most inner cycle, the j-cycle, is n-(i+1), the number of interactions calculated by each thread is

\sum_{i=a(k)}^{a(k+1)} n - (i+1)

This means that one would like find the discrete function a_k such that the functional

f[a_k] = \sum_{i=a(k)}^{a(k+1)} n - (i+1)

with the boundary conditions a(1)=0 and a(p)=n is a constant functional, thus forcing the number of interactions on each thread to be the same.

I've tried using different "heuristics"(e.g. a_k polynomial, exponential, log), and so far none have gave me a satisfactory answer. A direct solution of this problem is not evident to me.

For small p, this problem can be put on the "minimization sack problems" where basically each a_k is a variable to minimize the function

f(a_1,a_2,a_3,...) = sum(|f[a_k] - n/p|^2)

But has you might guess, this is not efficient (or even converge) for higher values of p.

Does anyone have any idea of how could this problem be tackled?

Comment: Have you considered using a less explicit distribution of load, by using queues? This way you can alter the set of interactions you consider (dropping insignificant ones, perhaps) and the load distribution mechanism can stay the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sorry if this is not expressed clearly, it makes sense in my head).

When adding up all the numbers from 1 to N, you can notice that N + 1 = (N - 1) + 2 = (N - 2) + 3, etc.

So, what if each thread used one small i and one large i, such that the sums always added up?

Or, say you wanted to always use 5 threads. Thread 1 would do the first 10% and the last 10%, thread 2 would do the second 10% and second-to-last 10%, and so on. Each pairing of an 'early' and 'late' section would add up to the same total number of interactions.

EDIT:

Stealing a diagram from another post...

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

0  - A B C D D C B A
1    - B C D D C B A  
2      - C D D C B A
3        - D D C B A  
4          - D C B A
5            - C B A
6              - B A
7                - A
8                  -
```

Does that show more clearly what I mean?

Comment: -1: Since this problem has a closed solution, I'm not so sure your solution is a valid solution... Either you try to show it, or else it is not clear it works...

Comment: I think the idea is to combine sections from the beginning and end of the outer loop.  It seems sound: row `i` has `N-1-i` couplings, row `N-2-i` has `N-1-(N-2-i)=i+1` couplings, so the total of the two has `N` couplings.  So, as long as you choose rows symmetrically from the beginning and end, you can split your problem into equal parts using a linear partition rule, instead of using square roots...

Comment: @Comingstorm - That's exactly what I was trying to express.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - this is obviously correct (once presented). The amount of work in rows i plus N-i is constant for any value of i. 1+8 = 2+7 = 3+6... This makes is easy, just run your i loop over half its range and for each i do work on both row i and N-i.

Answer (score 3):

You can divide your objects into `k` groups of roughly `N/k` bodies, and use this to dissect your initial triangle of interactions into `k*(k + 1)/2` pieces:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
                      -- N=9;  k=3;  N/k=3
0  - A A B B B C C C
1    - A B B B C C C  -- diagonal pieces:  A, D, F
2      - B B B C C C
3        - D D E E E  -- non-diagonal pieces: B, C, E
4          - D E E E
5            - E E E
6              - F F
7                - F
8                  -
```

This view is complicated by the fact that there are two kinds of pieces:  those along the diagonal (which are triangles with `(N/k)*(N/k - 1)/2` elements), and those which are not (which are squares with `(N/k)*(N/k)` elements).  However, since the diagonal pieces are roughly half the size of the square pieces, you can assign two to each thread to balance the load -- for a total of `k*k/2` roughly-equal tasks.

An advantage of this method is that each task only needs to access the data for `2*N/k` bodies, which could make it significantly more cache-friendly.

Comment: Alternatively, you could notice that Column 1 plus Column 8 adds up to 9 entries, as does 2 and 7, 3 and 6, and 4 and 5. Assigning each thread a combination of columns from the beginning and end wouldn't have that cache-friendly advantage, but it's easier to find which thread gets which entries.

Comment: My answer would need 2 outer loops, to iterate over the groups, plus 2 inner loops, to iterate over the members of the groups.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your compiler supports OpenMP, why can't you simply try to do

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) // or: schedule(guided)
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        // calculate interaction
```

or even (you'll need to benchmark to understand which one performs better)

```
#pragma omp parallel
const int stride = omp_get_num_threads() + 1; 
for (i = omp_get_thread_num(); i < n; i += stride)
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        // calculate interaction
```

Comment: +1 for the pragma omp. Its true, but trying to optimize it before actually implementing code is better. I'm not sure how the compiler deals with this: it doesn't know that each interaction is a constant time calculation, we know a priori

Comment: schedule(dynamic) and schedule(guided) are designed to handle the fact that each iteration doesn't take constant time (schedule(static) OTOH does not). also note that the second snippet does the computations in an interleaved manner, so that in the worst case the difference between the first and last thread is O(T*N) operations (T is the number of threads). actually this could be reduced to 0 by partial unrolling of the loop.

Comment: ok. See my answer... I think it justifies why this is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Today I just found the solution. I'm not accepting it till someone confirms it

In order to f[a_k] be a constant function with respect to k, then

f[a_{k+1}] - f[a_k] = 0

must be true for k = 1,2,3,...,p-1.

We can expand this equation using the definitions I've posted on the question, and we arrive to a system of "p" 2º order algebraic equations with respect to a_k, k=1,2,3,...,p. I'm not seeing a closed solution to an arbitrary p, but it can be analytically solved for each p.

I've confirmed that:

1. the sum, when using the a_k I've calculated was n(n-1)/2, the total number of interactions of this problem.
2. the number of interactions per thread is indeed constant for p = 2,3,4,5 and 10 (where the p=10 took some time to calculate on the mathematica®).

**EDIT**

After detailed inspection of the solutions for different values of p, I've reached to the general closed solution

a_k = 1/(2 p) (-p + 2 p n - sqrt[p^2 + 4 p (p + 1 - k) (n - 1) n])

which is valid for every p>=2, n>1.

This completes the answer.

Comment: Strange. Without diving to deep into it, the problem seems rather trivial for large n to me, if you don't need the absolute minimum, but a good approximation. Why not choose a(i) so that each a(i+1)^2-a(i)^2 is close to n^2/p?

Comment: see my edit, the closed solution does not suggests that a(i+1)^2-a(i)^2~n^2/p leads to a ~constant f[a_k].

Comment: Sure it does. Just choose `a(k) = n*sqrt(k/p)` (derived from my condition above) which for large n approximates your solution, but is way simpler. Additionally I would argue that you still fail to prove that your solution is the best solution: a(k) is integer, and your goal on a multithreaded system is to minimize max(a(k) for each k), because the slowest thread will determine the runtime.

Comment: For k = 2, p = 4, plot both your solution and mine as a function of n. You will see that they are not converging to each other... In particular, for n = 10.000, mine says the second thread (k=2) should begin in i = ~7000, yours says i = ~1000... this diference is proportional to n.

Comment: For k=2, p=4, n=10k I obtain a(2) = 10000*sqrt(2/4), which is 7070 (of my head). No need for plotting graphs...

Comment: lol, dum... stupidity in person... you are right. What was your reasoning to reach the a(i+1)^2-a(i)^2 = n^2/p? Post an answer that I accept it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but wrong. Your's says 7070, mine says 1340...it was the other way around. (For 1s I got scary... xD)

Comment: The number of couplings (in the innermost loop) is proportional to the square of n. The exact formula is `n*(n-1)/2`, the triangular numbers, but that doesn't matter - I am just looking at the highest exponent. Partition that into p separate parts - now you get `n^2/p` for the work each thread should do. The work a partition from a(k) to a(k+1) does is simplified the same way - hence a(k+1)^2-a(k)^2. To be exact use the triangular numbers there to, and you have a somewhat more complicated quadratic equation to solve. Your solution looks good, probably you missed a - or a * somewhere